# Vertical align items in Bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hopefully an easy one to solve. See image below, I cant get the toggle switch to align horizontally inline with the bootstrap buttons. I have some suspicions it may be to do with the css of this custom toggle switch. Nothing I've tried within the code on the razor page is having any affect. thx

[image]

Razor Page Code:

```
 <div class="container" style="margin-top: 2em">
<div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-sm">
        <div class="onoffswitch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch">
            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
                <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
            Button
            <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
            Button
            <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Custom CSS for Toggle Switch

```
.onoffswitch {
position: relative;
width: 70px;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox {
display: none;
}

.onoffswitch-label {
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
cursor: pointer;
border: 2px solid #999999;
border-radius: 0px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner {
display: block;
width: 200%;
margin-left: -100%;
transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    }

.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "ON";
    padding-left: 5px;
    background-color: #383B40;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "OFF";
    padding-right: 5px;
    background-color: #383B40;
    color: #999999;
    text-align: right;
}

.onoffswitch-switch {
display: block;
width: 30px;
margin: 0px;
background: #FF0000;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 40px;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
margin-left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
right: 0px;
background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add to your toggle those two class from **bootstrap 4**

```
class="d-flex align-items-center"
```

you can check more about it here in [documentaion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#align-items)

after that edit your `.onoffswitch-label` from

```
.onoffswitch-label {
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
cursor: pointer;
border: 2px solid #999999;
border-radius: 0px;
}
```

to

```
.onoffswitch-label {
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
cursor: pointer;
border: 2px solid #999999;
border-radius: 0px;
margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it just makes the red inner part of the toggle switch the same height as the bootstrap button and leaves the rest of the outer part of the switch graphics pushed up to the top line

Comment: i fix it,add to your `.onoffswitch-label` `margin: 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use css hack for that, look at the below code

```
html:
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">Content here</div>
</div>

css:
#parent {display: table}

#child {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
 }
```